# Retrive user information with JWT token

Tags: python, django, jwt

My function only shows access token API when I hit (user-info) API/login link. I want to show API tokens with user information. http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login/ link show API with user information

```
# Import libraries
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView
from base.api.serializers import UserSerializer
from base.models import User
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated, AllowAny
 
class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
@classmethod
def get_token(cls, user):
    token = super().get_token(user)

    # Add custom claims
    token['username'] = user.username

    return token

# Token Access
class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer

# Registration 
class RegisterView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)

# User information
class LoginView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request):
        user_id = request.user.id
        user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

API Token Access:
[image: API Token Access]

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify `MyTokenObtainPairSerializer` in this case.
First, make a new UserSerializer which will have the user information.

Like this :

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    isAdmin = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username',
                  'id',
                  'password',
                  ]

    def get_id(self, obj):  #they are unnecessary just example how you can link other fields using `SerializerMethodField`
        return obj.id

    def get_isAdmin(self, obj):
        return obj.is_staff
```

Then combine it with the token in `UserSerializerWithToken`

```
class UserSerializerWithToken(UserSerializer):
    token = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username',
                  'isAdmin',
                  # ...
                  'token']

    def get_token(self, obj):
        token = RefreshToken.for_user(obj)
        return str(token.access_token)
```

Then modify the Views

```
class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
        data = super().validate(attrs)

        serializer = UserSerializerWithToken(self.user).data 
        for k, v in serializer.items():
            data[k] = v

        return data
```

Now you can use `MyTokenObtainPairView` for login and it will have the user information and access and refresh token.

```
class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

login URL :

```
path('login/', views.MyTokenObtainPairView.as_view(),
```

Comment: @babarIbrar Hey check this out.